Calculating Historical FRA levels after Index transition
Recently Mexican interest rate market have switched from a 28day fixing to an OIS Index, similar to the transition from Libor to SOFR in US rates.
The OIS Index {MXIBTIEF Index} swap rate for the index started being published as of september 2024 which means also there is no FRA historical data. I am able to calculate the historical adjustment to the spot 28d fix one and extrapolate a historical rate.
Is there a way to reconstruct FRA histories using a formula rather than bootstrapping a yield curve for everyday and calculating the FRAs?

A 28d Fra is a forward looking projection of a term interest rate at a given time. I.e. it aggregates the 28days worth of interest rates into a single value.
The RFR is a 1d interest rate published at a certain time.
In order to approximate a 28drate with RFR rates you need to forecast all of the RFRs on a curve and aggregate them as of the required forecast date.
This is the same process as US Term SOFR rates. you can read how they constructed.
In short, yes you need to build a curve. If you want an approximatation use the closing 1m RFR rate on any given day and add FRA-RFR basis.

Thank you for the answer, but that doesn't really answer the question. The purpose is not to project the term rate, but rather to be able to reconstruct FRAs such as a 6m6m using the historical values of the 28day historical data adjusted/converted to OIS without bootstrapping. But it seems this is not possible without bootstrapping historical curves.
